# R: values inside list not reported as a vector c(1,2) but instead transformed to 1:2

Tags: r, list

```
> rates[[5]]
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

> rates[[6]]
[[1]]
[1] 2 1 1

> paste("$",rates[[5]],"$",rates[[6]],sep=" ")
[1] "$ 1:2 $ c(2, 1, 1)"
```

Please note what happens to rates[[5]] inside my paste. I do not understand why it doesn't adopt c(1,2) format.

Edit:

```
> typeof(rates[[5]])
[1] "list"
> typeof(rates[[6]])
[1] "list"

x <- rates[5:6]
> paste("$",x[[1]],"$",x[[2]],sep=" "); dput(x)
[1] "$ 1:2 $ c(2, 1, 1)"
list(list(1:2), list(c(2L, 1L, 1L)))
```

Comment: They both return "list".

Comment: Thank you. I just updated my question.

Comment: Yes, that thread is very helpful. Thanks for pointing it out. My problem is solved!